# SQL Server Sibling Records Count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, Contacts, Accounts. I am trying to create a general function that will get the number of records associated with same parent, here is what I have:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SiblingCount](
@IDValue Integer
)
RETURNS Integer AS 
BEGIN
      DECLARE @Result integer

      Select @Result = Count(a.AccountID)
      from Account a
      where a.Status <> 'Active' and
      a.ContactID = (select a2.ContactID 
      from Account a2 where a2.Accounnts = @IDValue)

      RETURN @Result
END

GO
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you really talking about *siblings*?  In your query you do not even touch the table `Contacts`... I think, that you have a 1:n relation between Concats and Accounts and what you really need is a count of *children*...

I think this could be done much easier like this:

```
SELECT c.ContactID,COUNT(*) AS CountAccounts
FROM Contacts AS c
INNER JOIN Accounts AS a ON c.ContactID=a.ContactID
WHERE a.Status<>'Active'
GROUP BY c.ContactID
```

Add a `AND c.ContactID=@IDValue` to the `WHERE` to reduce the result to the one line you need...

Comment: Thanks, I am using as a function to return count and I get Msg 444, Level 16, State 2, Procedure SiblingCount, Line 8
Select statements included within a function cannot return data to a client.

Comment: If you really need a function returning a scalar int value, you must do what you've done already: Declare a variable, use  `SELECT @Result=Count(*)... WHERE c.ContactID=@IDValue` (you can let away the `GROUP BY` in this case) and return the variable... But I doubt, that this is the best approach acutally... Smells very procedural...